# Excel goes non-responsive after I call a function that was defined earlier in the code

Tags: function, excel, vba

I have a situation where I am trying to use an Erlang calculator in my vba code.  I know that the Erlang code works because I have used it on its own before, but when I copy/paste the erlang code into another module/at the top of my code, I can't seem to call the function I need.  When I call it, Excel goes non-responsive and uses up a lot of memory.  I know that this likely means that there is an infinite loop somewhere, but I can't figure out where it is or if this is actually another issue that I'm not aware of.

The Erlang calculator is a free program, and I'm happy to give credit to this slick little bit of calculation.

The function that I'm calling:  agentno(  )

```
    'Version 1.0 Joanne Sparkes, Expedio Virtual Assistance Ltd for Call Centre Helper
    '18th November 2008
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Public Function utilisation(intensity As Double, agents As Long) As Double
    'Copyright Expedio Virtual Assistance Ltd 2008
    'calculates utilisation or agent occupancy
     On Error GoTo utilisationerror
        utilisation = intensity / agents

    utilisationexit:
        If utilisation < 0 Then utilisation = 0
        If utilisation > 1 Then utilisation = 1
    Exit Function

    utilisationerror:
        utilisation = 0
        Resume utilisationexit
    End Function

    Public Function top(intensity As Double, agents As Long) As Double
    'Copyright Expedio Virtual Assistance Ltd 2008
    'top row of Erlang-C Formula
        top = (intensity ^ agents) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(agents)
    End Function

    Public Function erlangBR(intensity As Double, agents As Long) As Double
    'Copyright Expedio Virtual Assistance Ltd 2008
    'calculates summed factorial element of Erlang-C formula
    Dim k As Long, max As Long, answer As Double

    k = 0
    max = agents - 1
    answer = 0

    For k = 0 To max
    answer = answer + ((intensity ^ k) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(k))
    Next k

    erlangBR = answer

    End Function

    Public Function ErlangC(intensity As Double, agents As Long) As Double
    'Copyright Expedio Virtual Assistance Ltd 2008
    'Brings together elements of Erlang C formula Top, Utilisation and ErlangBR
    On Error GoTo ErlangCError
    ErlangC = (top(intensity, agents)) / ((top(intensity, agents)) + ((1 -utilisation  (intensity, agents)) * erlangBR(intensity, agents)))

    ErlangCExit:
        If ErlangC < 0 Then ErlangC = 0
        If ErlangC > 1 Then ErlangC = 1
    Exit Function

    ErlangCError:
        Resume ErlangCExit

    End Function

    Public Function Servicelevel(intensity As Double, agents As Long, target As Double, duration As Double) As Double
    'Copyright Expedio Virtual Assistance Ltd 2008
    'calculation of service level
    On Error GoTo servicelevelerror

    Servicelevel = 1 - (ErlangC(intensity, agents) * Exp(-(agents - intensity) * target / duration))

    Servicelevelexit:
    If Servicelevel > 1 Then Servicelevel = 1
    If Servicelevel < 0 Then Servicelevel = 0
    Exit Function

    servicelevelerror:
        Servicelevel = 0
        Resume Servicelevelexit

    End Function

    Public Function agentno(intensity As Double, target As Double, duration As Double, servreq As Double) As Long
    'Copyright Expedio Virtual Assistance Ltd 2008
    'calculates minimum agent numbers for required service level
    Dim agents As Long, minagents As Long

    minagents = Int(intensity)
    agents = minagents

    While Servicelevel(intensity, agents, target, duration) < servreq
    agents = agents + 1
    Wend

    agentno = agents

    End Function
```

Sorry about the long code, but I felt that to actually be able to figure out what's going on, it would require it.

Anyway, I try to call the agentno() function (passing along the needed stuff), and I can't get it to work.

Here's where I'm trying to use it:

```
    For icount = 1 To 22
        For jcount = 1 To 6
            intensity = ((CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) / 1800) * duration) 'Calculates the intensity at each interval.
            AgentsNeeded(icount, jcount) = agentno(intensity, target, duration, servreq) '      <---         <---       <---          <---THIS IS THE ONE GIVING ME TROUBLE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        Next jcount
    Next icount
```

I have done debug.print tests and found that the intensity is correctly calcualted (I removed it for the purposes of posting here), so I know that everything works up to that point, but as soon as agentno() is called, Excel stops responding and uses up a lot of memory as stated above.  The array AgentsNeeded() seems to be just fine as well as it was declared at the beginning of all my code.

What am I missing?

Comment: The code you posted is not enough to run the sample, it misses functions and values for variables. My guess however would be you never exit the `While/Wend` in `agentno`. Set a breapoint on `agents = agents + 1` and keep looping through manualy, observing variable contents on each loop.

Comment: You are correct.  It is getting stuck in the while/wend loop.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  Can I post the .xlsm file so that you have the whole code to date?

Comment: Well apparently your `servreq` is not being met, which can be if it's greater than `1`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks GSerg!  I've been doing a little more debugging, and I found that Servicelevel is only returning a number that approaches, and eventually becomes, 1.  I'll have to do some more work on this to figure out how to fix that.  I appreciate your help and insight on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did more debugging as GSerg suggested, and it was the servreq that was causing the issue.  I was unaware that it actually passed a decimal to the function, so when I figured this out, it was a quick fix to get it working.

Thanks again to GSerg to prodding a newb like me along the right path. :D